# How to get custom-resource file after packaging Metro App?

Tags: html, microsoft-metro, package, winjs, resource-files

I have a Metro application in which am using different service URLs for receiving the data.For this scenario I want to change service URLs after building my application into a package.I have followed adding resource files into my app as mentioned in MSDN sites and tested by using following code.

```
var resourceLoader = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader();
var resourceString =  resourceLoader.getString("greeting");
```

Here am getting greeting **resource** value string in my app before packaging.After packaging am not able to see my resource files but am able to see default resource files like en-US,fr-FR etc but.
Can anyone suggest some solution to get custom-resource file after packaging?

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it you need to add the resource files before packaging the app... after that's done, you can not additional resources... what you could do is getting the new service url from a service and save it locally as a setting or in your DB

**edit:** also, `resourceLoader.getString("greeting").value;` will give you the actual string, or "greeting" in case no resources were found